"Fast RWI is used" prompting when launching my app on Samsung Tizen TV 2018 Modal
I've encountered a Fast RWI popup appearing before my Tizen app loads. My application works fine on most other TV models, including Tizen 2021 and Tizen 2022, but I am experiencing this unexpected popup only on the Tizen 2018 platform.
Pop-up Message is below
> RWI mapping info 7011(RWI):… 7012(RWI):N/A 7013(RWI):N/AFast RWI is used, [about:blank] is loaded fist instead of [my domain link is appeared here] Click OK button will start the real loading. Notes:Please connect to RWI in PC before click OK button. Then you can get network log from the initial loading. Please click Record button in Timeline panel in PC before click OK button, Then you can get profile log from the initial loading.
Can you please give me some suggestion to get rid of this popup in Tizen Tv 2018 modal
I am still confused and struggling to get an idea what is happening.
Unfortunately i didn't find any clue

I've attached similiar question and answer. Let us know the result after firmware update. https://forum.developer.samsung.com/t/debugging-message-on-production/287
